# Как сделать что бы foreach js перебирал элементы другим способом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста с таким вопросом. Есть цикл Javascript который перебирает элементы стандартным образом. Однако их рассположение в Dom дереве не соответствует нужному мне.

[image: Doom]

Вот пример. Можно ли сделать что бы цикл foreach перебирал по аттрибуту data-loop. От маленького до большого. Заранее спасибо

Comment: перед проходом отсортируй элементы по нужному свойству

Answer (score 1):

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

Array.from(divs).sort((a, b) => {
return +a.dataset.loop - +b.dataset.loop
}).forEach((div) => {
console.log(div)
})
```

```html
<div  data-loop="2">1</div>
  <div   data-loop="1">2</div>
  <div   data-loop="3">3</div>
```